# php hit counter showing hits back to back

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a hit counter where a hit will be recoreded when the user visits the page, and again if user comes after 1 hour. But I dont know why it is not working, whenever i refresh the page a hit is being recorded

I think there is a problem in date and time function but I dont know what.

This is my hit counter code

```
if($dbqueries->Query('SELECT * FROM hits WHERE userId = ?, ip = ?', [$profileId, $ip])){
            if($dbqueries->rowCount() > 0){
                $row = $dbqueries->fetch();
               $date = $row->date;
            }
        }
        echo $date;
        $hit = $dbqueries->Query('SELECT `date` FROM hits WHERE userId = ?, ip = ? ORDER BY DESC', [$profileId, $ip]);

        if(!$hit || (new \DateTime)->modify('-1 hours') > (new \DateTime($date))){
            echo 'Good';
            $dbqueries->Query("INSERT INTO hits (`userId`, `date`, `ip`) VALUES ('{$profileId}', '{$date}', '{$ip}')");
        }
```

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: You have SQL syntax error right here: `WHERE userId = ?, ip = ?` should be `WHERE userId = ? and ip = ?`

Answer (score 1):

The where syntax should be

```
SELECT * FROM hits WHERE userId = ? AND ip = ?
```

and

```
SELECT `date` FROM hits WHERE userId = ? AND ip = ? ORDER BY DESC
```